# Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC drivers for fedora 38

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers, kde, realtek

my Internet connection is not working well, where can I download the driver for my Wi-Fi adapter Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC?
My laptop Huawei D14 nbl-waq9r

Comment: Try this one on [github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88)

Comment: *not working well* doesn't really provide a lot of information on the actual issue, that might or might not be solved with a new driver.